# AWS how to create CMK key from Java for specific IAM user

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Whenever I try to create a CMK key I get an error: **{"errorMessage":"User: arn:aws:sts:: [...] is not authorized to perform: kms:CreateKey**.

How can I create the CMK key for a specific IAM user? I'm guessing I need to invoke that user's IAM policy?

```
AWSKMS kms = AWSKMSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

String desc = "My CMK key";

CreateKeyRequest createCMKreq = new 
CreateKeyRequest().withDescription(desc);
CreateKeyResult createCMKresult = kms.createKey(createCMKreq);
```

Comment: by implementing some conditional statements?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, of course but problem is how. That's why I'm asking...

Comment: @BakedInhalf, *"create the CMK key for a specific IAM user"* ... did you intend to ask how to *allow a specific user to create a CMK*?  It's a little bit unclear, since CMKs aren't exactly "for" users, though permission to access them can be granted to specific users.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sorry about that. I want to create a CMK key, probably by a lambda function, and that lamda should run when the IAM user logs in for the first time. The key itself should be used for encrypt/decrypt of the user's files when he/she saves them in a bucket..

Comment: @BakedInhalf there are some apparent problems with your plan.  I'm not aware of being able to trigger a Lambda function on first login, and not sure why you want/need one CMK per user, though it should be possible. (There's a $1/mo charge per CMK).  CMKs are only usable within a single AWS region, which means all the buckets the user uses would need to be in a single region or you'd need more than one key per user.  It sounds complicated... you might want to explain the use case more thoroughly... including how users will access S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot One region is fine. Upon login you can edit and save a document in a web interface (like google docs). That document should be encrypted automaticly in your bucket once you save it. So maybe S3 AES 256 encryption is sufficent, and AWS-KMS is not needed?

Answer (score 2):

You need IAM User to have **AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser** managed policy to attached to the user.

You can attach this Policy :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:CreateAlias",
            "kms:CreateKey",
            "kms:DeleteAlias",
            "kms:Describe*",
            "kms:GenerateRandom",
            "kms:Get*",
            "kms:List*",
            "kms:TagResource",
            "kms:UntagResource",
            "iam:ListGroups",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "iam:ListUsers"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
 ]
}
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: This might work, but seems like it grants excessive privilege relative to the task described in the question.

Comment: You can remove unwanted access from the list as per your needs also refer AWS Policy Generator:
https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: @KushVyas I attached this policy to my role, that the lambda is using.. Now I can list keys! I will try and create keys also :)

Comment: @BakedInhalf Good to know tell me how it goes and mark it as answer when it works :)

Comment: @KushVyas So now I can create CMK KMS key. But I also need to attach that specifik KMS key to a user? Or how does KMS know that a user I created should use this new key?

Comment: Please Refer to this document :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-example

Answer (score 1):

Please atach below policy to your IAM user policy,

```js
{
  "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {"AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/KMSUser",
    "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/KMSRole", // ADD ALL NEEDED USERS HERE
    "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"
  ]},,
  "Action": "kms:*", //CHANGE * IF YOU DON'T NEED FULL PERMISSION
  "Resource": "*" //CHANGE * IF YOU DON'T NEED FULL PERMISSION
}
```

**Giving '*' for permission is not all a good idea as it will provide full access. So please narrow down the permission according to your requirment.**

It would be worth read below two official documentation on the same,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/control-access-overview.html

Comment: This might work, but seems like it grants excessive privilege relative to the task described in the question.

Comment: Yes, but an inexperienced user might incorrectly assume `"Action": "kms:*"` is *required* and end up with an insecure environment as a result of this advice.  IAM policy language seems intimidating and frustrating to many new users and there is a temptation to find something that appears to work, without understanding that it permits far more than was intended.

Comment: My suggestion is to provide only, exactly what OP needs in the policy... and, honestly, I believe some "what have you tried?" or more clarification from him or her is needed before we understand exactly what is being asked.

Comment: All right. I have edited a bit in the principal section of user policy. There we can mention which users to add.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I want a lambda function that creates a KMS-CMK key when the user logs in for the first time. So right now I'm just developing the lambda function.. I'm guessing this is how you must set it up?

Comment: @BakedInhalf Yes while creating Lambda please provide the same Role with the policy you have created. You would be able to see dropdown in Lambda configuration tab to select Role. Please select 'Choose an existing rule' then in the existing rule dropdown you would be able to see the role you have created in IAM.